# Separate action method for a partial-view control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

In my asp.net-mvc3 project I use a partial views on a page. That partial view is reusable and will present on several pages. 
Partial view has input controls that I can put data in. There are other controls on the page that are specific to the page. Partial view sits inside of the page form. When data entered in the partial view control and other page specific controls single request will be submitted to the controller action method.

As the partial view control is reusable it will be shown on several pages. 
I would like to have one action for the partial view, separated from the page controller action, which will be invoked when entire form submitted. Basically not to process data in every page controller action where partial view will appear.

Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Maybe providing some source code will make it clearer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Edited. Any better now?

Comment: No, not better for me. Code please.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov don't have code, it's a concept, to actually convince my lead to go with mvc rather than WebForms.

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid that StackOverflow is a specific programming related Q&A site, not a tips for management convincing to migrate from WebForms to ASP.NET MVC Q&A site. Once you have a specific question don't hesitate to come back here and ask it. You will have to provide of course the code you have tried so far and the specific programming problem you are encountering with your code. If you are unable to provide and talk about code that you probably should not be asking here.

Comment: Well, that's your opinion. Mine is different. Until I don't see code in your question, for me your question is not specific. Hopefully someone else will think differently and will be able to answer your question. Good luck with convincing your management by the way :-)

Comment: Thank you @DarinDimitrov for you response. I respect your answer as many others and knowledge you share here.

Comment: The question is very straight forward.  He wants to have a partial view own all the logic it needs to do CRUD operations, as opposed to having the main Action method being called having to repeat the loading of data into that partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @StanK for giving direction where to look, solution appeared to be not difficult at all. Html.Action or Html.RenderAction do exactly what I needed.

Here is the example:

Page form where partial view will be inserted

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProduct", "Home"))
{
    Product code: <input type="text" name="ProductCode" /><br />
    ....
    .... 
    <!-- partial view control -->
    @Html.Action("Calendar", "Calendar")
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

PartialView.cshtml (control html view)

```
Date: <input type="text" name="CreateDate" />
```

Domain Object

```
 public class MyCalendar
 { 
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Calendar Controller

```
public class CalendarController : Controller
{

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Calendar(MyCalendar cal)
    {
        // Do something with data

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometime you just need to know the right term to google!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I have really understood what you are asking, but I think the concept you are looking for is known as "Child Actions".

This essentially lets a PartialView have it's own action method, meaning the main view rendering the Child Action does not need to be concerned at all about the model the Partial View requires - the logic for this is contained in the Child Action.

But you will probably need to Google Child Actions and read up on them to see if they will actually do what you need them to do.